# Pedir confirmación web para eliminar archivos con PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito realizar algo simple, pero no entiendo el como.

Necesito borrar un archivo o directorio con PHP, lo cual es simple:

```
<?php
  $ruta = "/ruta/al/directorio/archivo.txt";
  if(file_exists($ruta)){
    unlink();
  }
?>
```

Ahora lo que quiero es agregar un popup para confirmar el borrado
Pero necesito capturar la respuesta:

```
<?php
  $ruta = "/ruta/al/directorio/archivo.txt";
  if(file_exists($ruta)){
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    return window.confirm( '¿Borrar?' );
  }
  </script>
<?php
    if(valorRetonado == true){
      unlink();
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Eso no se puede hacer en PHP, tiene que ser desde HTML. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código (HTML, probablemente un enlace o formulario) que usas para llegar a ese PHP.

Comment: No tengo HTML de por medio, recibo una ruta por medio del PHP, la cual es simulada en el ejemplo. Esa ruta se revisa si es directorio o archivo y si se puede eliminar o no, bajo las condiciones esta eliminándose correctamente, pero ahora quieren una confirmación para eliminar dicho archivo, cuando el proceso debe ser si es posible eliminar, se elimina.

Comment: El problema es que PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor y no puede generar acciones en el cliente (navegador), a menos que hagas un HTML intermedio para pedir la confirmación.

Comment: Entonces no hay forma de hacer eso... Por que no, no quiero que se ejecute de nuevo el código y no necesito mandar ajax o jquery para eso...

Comment: Supongo que antes del proceso sí hay un HTML, ahí podrías poner un checkbox para indicar que se elimine el archivo o directorio e incluir la confirmación.

Comment: No por que las rutas obtenidas terminan siendo dinámicas, si existiera algo antes de iniciar, no sabrian que cosas borran, solo borrarian.

Comment: Uso de checkbox + confirmación: "Esta acción podría eliminar archivos o directorios, marque esta casilla para confirmar". O una simple confirmación al procesar el formulario o enlace original.